# Loop that creates rectangle shapes in PPT based on table/range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

asked a question on stackoverflow a while ago that dealt with creating shapes in PPT based on data input by the user. After gradually expanding my code i am now able to create shapes based on excel data in PPT. (At the same time my questions are now too far from the original question)
However, since i worked with a fixed number of variables given the case that i would like to create a varying number of shapes based on the excel data, i would have to change the code everytime i want to create e.g. more shapes than the code originally was designed for.

So what i did was try this code

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim w1 As Integer
Dim w2 As Integer
Dim w3 As Integer
Dim FileStr As String
Dim TabStr As String
Dim Cell As String
Dim XLApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ObjXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim Value As Integer
Dim Value2 As Integer
Dim Value3 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim zahl As Integer
FileStr = "C:\Users\mjschmitt\Documents\VBATest\Test.xlsx"
Set ObjXL = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileStr)
i = ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B1").Value = i
For zahl = 1 To i
Do
Value = ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cell(zahl, "A").Value
w1 = Value
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(35)
myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=w1, Height:=200
Loop Until zahl = i
Next
End Sub
```

But i get "Runtime error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method".
The debugger does not even point me to the wrong line so i am pretty lost at this point. How could i properly implement this loop?`

Thanks!

(Code that worked

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim w1 As Integer
Dim w2 As Integer
Dim w3 As Integer
Dim FileStr As String
Dim TabStr As String
Dim Cell As String
Dim XLApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ObjXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim Value As Integer
Dim Value2 As Integer
Dim Value3 As Integer
FileStr = "C:\Users\username\Documents\VBATest\Test.xlsx"
Set ObjXL = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileStr)
Value = ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value
Value2 = ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B1").Value
Value3 = ObjXL.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("C1").Value
w1 = Value
w2 = Value2
w3 = Value3
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(35)

myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=w1, Height:=200
myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=w2, Height:=200
myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=w3, Height:=200
End Sub
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code to see what line the error occurs on.  I'm guessing that it's on Set ObjXL = XLApp.Workbooks etc.  You haven't yet created an XLApp object, so you can't reference it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. It DID work , before i tried to implement the loop..or does a loop require a special kind of reference? Added the code that worked above (for having an easier read)

Comment: FYI --- it seems like you have two loops when you need one: A `Do` loop nested inside a `For` loop. I don't think that causes the run-time error, but it looks like a bug.

Comment: There is no `Worksheet.Cell()` function/method. Try `Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, zahl)`. That's Cell**s** (plural).

Comment: Perfect! That worked! it was the cells AND i had to remove the double loop as that caused the whole makro to just crash. Thanks a bunch! (Would like to upvote your answer, but somehow i dont seem to find the right button...)